# Building an xml document from functions that return DOMNodes

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

My question is a rather simple one for anyone familiar with the DOM* classes in PHP.
Basically i have different classes that i want to return to me something that I can append in my xml document

Following pseudo-code should demonstrate better

```
Class ChildObject{ function exportToXML( return a DOMNode ? ) }

Class ContainerObject{ 
function exportToXML(){
    $domSomething = new DOM*SOMETHING*;
    foreach($children as $child) $domSomething->appendChild($child->exportToXML);
    return $domSomething ;
} 
}


Now i want to create the entire DOMDocument

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$root = $xml->createElement('root');
foreach($containers as $container) $root->appendChild($container->exportToXML());
```

I tried sending the DOMDocument object as a reference, did not work. I tried creating DOMNodes but didn't work as well....so i'm looking at a simple answer: what datatypes do i need to return in order for me to achieve the above functionality?

```
<?php
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $h = $xml->createElement('hello');

    $node1 = new DOMNode('aaa'); 
    $node1->appendChild(new DOMText('new text content'));
    //node1 is being returned by a function

    $node2 = new DOMNode('bbb');
    $node2->appendChild(new DOMText('new text content'));
    //node2 is being returned by some other function

    $h->appendChild($node1);//append to this element the returned node1
    $h->appendChild($node2);//append to this element the returned node2

    $xml->appendChild($h);//append to the document the root node

    $content = $xml->saveXML();
    file_put_contents('xml.xml', $content);//output to an xml file
?>
```

The above code should do the following:

consider that i want to build the following xml

```
<hello>
 <node1>aaa</node1>
 <node2>bbb</node2>
</hello>
```

node1 could be again a node that has multiple children so node1 could be as well as something like this:

```
<node1>
 <child1>text</child1>
 <child2>text</child2>
 <child3>
  <subchild1>text</subchild1>
 </child3>
</node1>
```

Basically when i call exportToXML() something should be returned, call it $x that i can append in my document using $xml->appendChild($x);

I want to create the above structure and return the object that can be appended in the DOMDocument

Comment: `return a DOMNode ?` -> Yes, see http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php

Comment: i have edited my question, please check it out and tell me what you think..this is pretty annoying.

Comment: You should enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), that code gives: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNode::createTextNode().

Comment: ok if you know how to do it can you post the answer using that code i just added? i am really stuck here. I get this error now: PHP Warning:  DOMNode::appendChild() [<a href='domnode.appendchild'>domnode.appendchild</a>]: Couldn't fetch DOMNode

Comment: What should `new DOMNode('aaa');` do? Can you explain that to me? Then I might better understand what your problem is, I don't know the code, I can only help you, that's all.

Comment: i have changed the code snippet and added comments. do you understand now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3916/discussion-between-user253530-and-hakre)

Comment: Nah, let's continue in comments.

Comment: ok post your explanation here...either way is good as long as i get this running

Comment: I repeat my last question again as it's not yet answered. What should `new DOMNode('aaa');` do? What is it?

Comment: i have edited my question again. do you undertand now?

Comment: Ah, you want to add a `DOMElement` which is a *sub-type of* `DOMNode` - try with `new DOMElement('aaa');` instead.

Comment: no, i want to create a structure of nodes that can be appended wherever i want. Basically i want my functions to create small Nodes (that can have child nodes which again can have child nodes) and then return them. The returned data should be appended in a DOMDocument. Post some sample code if you understand my request.

Comment: `DOMElement` **is** a `DOMNode`, you can do it with that. Just add small `DOMElement` Nodes, add children to them and then append it to where-ever you want. Unless you can't do it with `DOMElement` is still can not understand what you request, so I can't post code. But I have the feeling you're really close to get it finished.

Comment: no it didn't do the trick...thanks very much for the help. I'm going to send the DOMDocument and element in which to append the data as params to the functions. That works.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$h = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('hello'));

$node1 = $h->appendChild($xml->createElement('aaa'));
$node1->appendChild($xml->createTextNode('new text content'));

$node2 = $h->appendChild($xml->createElement('bbb'));
$node2->appendChild($xml->createTextNode('new text content'));

$xml->save("xml.xml");
?>
```

will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hello>
    <aaa>new text content</aaa>
    <bbb>new text content</bbb>
</hello>
```

Your example XML showed `<node1>aaa</node1>` but I think your various code snippet examples went out of sync when you were editing =) In case you need that output, try:

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$h = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('hello'));

$node1 = $h->appendChild($xml->createElement('node1'));
$node1->appendChild($xml->createTextNode('aaa'));

$node2 = $h->appendChild($xml->createElement('node2'));
$node2->appendChild($xml->createTextNode('bbb'));

$xml->save("xml.xml");
?>
```